# How can I make my texture loopable on a cube

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, vector-mapping

I'm trying to put this loopable wallpaper on this wall and no matter how i mess with the UVs, i cant make it loop. is there some other way to do this?

[here is the blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lOjm9XuPltEsY8HlDVMgiWVWZSqoh7wY/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see if you select the 2 orthogonal faces, their UVs are not adjacent in the *UV Editor*, they overlap, therefore the image doesn't adjust:

[image]

You can select the face ring and simply <kbd>U</kbd> > *Unwrap*:

[image]

The texture will follow all around except where there is a cut. But you can scale up or down the UV faces until it adjusts:

[image]